# Xcode not detecting Pods directory

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management

I am working with a colleague on a Swift application and we are managing our versions through github. He has added some CocoaPods.

I have run

`gem install cocoapods`
`pod install`

The proj/Pods directory is populated with Pods, however on the very first `import`, Xcode fails to build with `No such module Alamofire`, and Xcode does not see anything other then`Pods.debug.xcconfig` and `Pods.release.xcconfig` in the Pods directory.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should open `.xcworkspace`, not `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: I ended up having to reopen the directory. Thank you so much!

Comment: Answers should be answers--not questions.  Can you please rephrase this answer.